# Display tables between two numbers

Tags: vbscript, scripting, do-while

I have been trying to create a VB script using the "Do While" loop in the VBScript. I want to generate tables between two numbers accepted from the user I don't know what's wrong with this:

```
option explicit 

Dim i, a, j, product, table

a = inputbox("enter a number")
For i=1 to a
  j=1
  Do while(j<=10)
    product=i*j
    a=i&"*"&j&"="&product
    table=table&vbnewline&a
  loop
  msgbox table
next
```

The above results in a blank window.

Can anyone help me resolve the problem?

P.S.
I managed to get it to work using the "For" loop.

Comment: Well, you're not incrementing `j`, so I would imagine your `Do Loop` runs forever.

Comment: Yes, it does, The initial value of j is 1 and it should run until 10?

Comment: Then increment it in your loop: `j = j + 1`

Comment: Then you need to manually increment it or use a second `For` loop instead of the `Do While` loop.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't show the result. Does it execute "Do while" loop?

Comment: **option explicit 

Dim i, a, j, product, table

a = inputbox("enter a number")
For i=1 to a
  j=j+1
  Do while(j<=10)
    product=i*j
    a=i&"*"&j&"="&product
    table=table&vbnewline&a
  loop
  msgbox table
next**

The above results in nothing. I mean if I use **j+1** instead **j** , it shows nothing.

Comment: You're not incrementing `j` _in_ your `Do Loop`. How is your `Do Loop` ever supposed to end if `j` never gets incremented?

Comment: @DrasticdreamerDrasticity - See the code in the answer below. Those are two options for creating a loop that runs 10 times.

Comment: Okay. You mean it should be used as "Do while (j=j+1)"?

Comment: @DrasticdreamerDrasticity - Nope. It needs to be like I've shown it below.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Use a `For` loop:

```
Dim i
For i = 1 To 10
    ' This will run 10 times
Next
```

Option 2: Use a `Do While` loop:

```
Dim j
j = 1
Do While j <= 10
    ' This will also run 10 times
    j = j + 1
Loop
```

**Edit**:

If you need to loop on both `i` and `j`, you can create a *nested* `For` loop:

```
Dim i, j
For i = 1 To 10
    For j = 1 To 10
        ' This will run 10 times for each value of i (so 100 total)
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Bond. It works now. Yes, it should have been incremented in the "Do-While" loop. Thanks again!